# extract text between a pair of parenthesis using awk

Tags: postgresql, awk, plpgsql

We have an SQL file with function definitions. We want to read this file and prepare another SQL file with all the drop DDL statements for all the functions in the first SQL file.

For example the first sql has the content like this:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION folder_cycle_check (folder_key INTEGER, new_parent_folder_key INTEGER) RETURNS VOID AS $procedure$

DECLARE 
    parent_of_parent INTEGER;
BEGIN
    IF folder_key = new_parent_folder_key THEN
        RAISE EXCEPTION 'Illegal cycle detected',new_parent_folder_key;
    END IF;
SELECT INTO parent_of_parent  (SELECT parent_folder_key FROM folder where folder_key = new_parent_folder_key);

IF new_parent_folder_key IS NOT NULL THEN
    PERFORM folder_cycle_check(folder_key, parent_of_parent);
END IF;

END; $procedure$
LANGUAGE plpgsql;
```

Now I want to create the target SQL file as:

```
DROP FUNCTION folder_cycle_check((folder_key INTEGER, new_parent_folder_key INTEGER)
```

For this to achieve I have a "genDrop.txt" file which I pass to awk.exe command along with the first SQL file. The problem with the "genDrop.txt" is that it is only generating the target SQL file with drop statements as:

```
DROP FUNCTION folder_cycle_check
which is not useful because PostgreSQL wants like this:
DROP FUNCTION folder_cycle_check(folder_key INTEGER, new_parent_folder_key INTEGER)
```

Can anybody help me? I am new to the awk programming. 
FYI, the "genDrop.txt" is this:

```
#######################################################################
# AWK program to generate drop statements from create table, procedure, and view statements
############################################################################

function dropit(objtype, objname, rulename)
{
#   l[lines++] = "DROP " objtype " " objname " -- Line " NR ", Rule " rulename;
    l[lines++] = "DROP " objtype " " objname 
    next
}

function dropitpg(objtype, objname, funcargs, rulename)
{
#   l[lines++] = "DROP " objtype " " objname " -- Line " NR ", Rule " rulename;
    l[lines++] = "DROP " objtype " " objname " " funcargs
    next
}


BEGIN { FS="[ (;]*" }
# trim the line
{$2 = $2 }
# "grab creates" 
/^ +[Cc][Rr][Ee][Aa][Tt][Ee] *[Pp][Rr][Oo][Cc]/             {dropit($3, $4, "CPs") }
/^[Cc][Rr][Ee][Aa][Tt][Ee] *[Pp][Rr][Oo][Cc]/               {dropit($2, $3, "CP") }

/^ +[Cc][Rr][Ee][Aa][Tt][Ee] *[Oo][Rr] *[Rr][Ee][Pp][Ll][Aa][Cc][Ee] *[Pp][Rr][Oo][Cc]/ {dropit($5, $6, "CPs") }
/[Cc][Rr][Ee][Aa][Tt][Ee] *[Oo][Rr] *[Rr][Ee][Pp][Ll][Aa][Cc][Ee] *[Pp][Rr][Oo][Cc]/    {dropit($4, $5, "CP") }


/^ +[Cc][Rr][Ee][Aa][Tt][Ee] *[Vv][Ii][Ee][Ww]/             {dropit($3, $4, "CVs") }
/[Cc][Rr][Ee][Aa][Tt][Ee] *[Vv][Ii][Ee][Ww]/                {dropit($2, $3, "CV") }

/^ +[Cc][Rr][Ee][Aa][Tt][Ee] *[Oo][Rr] *[Rr][Ee][Pp][Ll][Aa][Cc][Ee] *[Vv][Ii][Ee][Ww]/ {dropit($5, $6, "CRVs") }
/[Cc][Rr][Ee][Aa][Tt][Ee] *[Oo][Rr] *[Rr][Ee][Pp][Ll][Aa][Cc][Ee] *[Vv][Ii][Ee][Ww]/    {dropit($4, $5, "CRV") }


/^ +[Cc][Rr][Ee][Aa][Tt][Ee] *[Tt][Aa][Bb][Ll][Ee]/             {dropit($3, $4, "CTs") }
/^[Cc][Rr][Ee][Aa][Tt][Ee] *[Tt][Aa][Bb][Ll][Ee]/           {dropit($2, $3, "CT") }

/^ +[Cc][Rr][Ee][Aa][Tt][Ee] *[Ss][Ee][Qq][Uu][Ee][Nn][Cc][Ee]/     {dropit($3, $4, "CSs") }
/[Cc][Rr][Ee][Aa][Tt][Ee] *[Ss][Ee][Qq][Uu][Ee][Nn][Cc][Ee]/    {dropit($2, $3, "CS") }

/^ +[Cc][Rr][Ee][Aa][Tt][Ee] *[Ff][Uu][Nn][Cc][Tt][Ii][Oo][Nn]/     {dropit($3, $4, "CSs") }
/[Cc][Rr][Ee][Aa][Tt][Ee] *[Ff][Uu][Nn][Cc][Tt][Ii][Oo][Nn]/    {dropit($2, $3, "CS") }


END{
    print "-- Beginning " lines " drop statements"
    for (i = lines - 1; i >= 0; --i) {
    print l[i]
    print EOS
    print ""
    }
    print "-- End of " lines " drop statements"
}

BEGIN { FS="[ ;]*" }
/^ +[Cc][Rr][Ee][Aa][Tt][Ee] *[Oo][Rr] *[Rr][Ee][Pp][Ll][Aa][Cc][Ee] *[Ff][Uu][Nn][Cc][Tt][Ii][Oo][Nn]/     {dropitpg($5, $7, "CSs") }
/[Cc][Rr][Ee][Aa][Tt][Ee] *[Oo][Rr] *[Rr][Ee][Pp][Ll][Aa][Cc][Ee] *[Ff][Uu][Nn][Cc][Tt][Ii][Oo][Nn]/    {sed -nr "s/\s*\[([^\]+)\]/\1/p" }

END{
    print "-- Beginning " lines " drop statements"
    for (i = lines - 1; i >= 0; --i) {
    print l[i]
    print EOS
    print ""
    }
    print "-- End of " lines " drop statements"
}
```

Comment: I read this 3 times now and I don't understand the question

Comment: your example output (in the 2nd code block) shows 2 opening parens, is that what you really want? Good luck.

Answer (score 1):

If your example output (minus the extra open-paren) is all you need then I think your script is over-kill. How about this?

```
#! /bin/awk -f
{
  if ($2 ~ /[Ff][Uu][Nn][Cc][Tt][Ii][Oo][Nn]/ ) {
      funcName=$3
      argSig=$0
      srchTarg= "^.*" funcName
      sub(srchTarg,"",argSig)
      # print "argSig=" argSig
      sub(/[\)].*$/, ")", argSig)
      # print "argSig=" argSig
      print "DROP FUNCTION " funcName argSig
    }
}
```

be sure to `chmod 755 genDrop.awk`

**sample run**

(I changed the first line of your sample input to )

> CREATE FUNCTION folder_cycle_check (....

**sample run**

```
$ genDrop.awk dropFunction.txt
DROP FUNCTION folder_cycle_check (folder_key INTEGER, new_parent_folder_key INTEGER)
```

Also, naming your awk script as genDrop.txt has not helped in communicating what your intention is, surely you mean genDrop.awk